# Tailwind CSS classes not loaded in npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, tailwind-css, postcss

I created a Npm package using Vite(React) and TailwindCSS. My package is working but when I installed it in a project, the CSS is not working.

How to configure my package so that it takes the CSS into account when installed in another project ?

The package can be found here : [Paginated Table React](https://github.com/thaisrodez/paginated-table-react)

vite.config.js :

```
import path from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/lib/index.jsx'),
      name: 'paginated-table-react-pkg',
      fileName: (format) => `paginated-table-react-pkg.${format}.js`
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                require('tailwindcss')({
                    config: './tailwind.config.js'
                }),
             ],
        }
    },
})
```

Tailwind config :

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
 content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Postcss config :

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

I am using :
"postcss": "^8.4.25",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
"vite": "^4.4.2",

Thanks !

I tried adding a css object in my vite.config file :

```
css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                require('tailwindcss')({
                    config: './tailwind.config.js'
                }),
             ],
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue by adding a link to my package in my project tailwind config :

```js
content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./node_modules/paginated-table-react-pkg/**/*.{html,js, jsx}"
  ],
```

Comment: You have answered the question by explaining what to do, but you should also explain more of the how with more supporting information.

Comment: Is there another solution? This might be fine for you but I would assume most users wont want to have to add ui libraries to their tailwind.config